# Filament Dependent Modals

Tags: laravel, laravel-filament

I have a repeater that contains a select (option) and a multi-select (values) where I added a create form for both so the user can add an unexisting option/value.

But values are option dependent so I am trying to pass the option_id from the repeater to the create form modal and I'm just stuck with null when I try to die dump data.

```
Repeater::make('Product Options')
                    ->relationship('productOptions')
                    ->schema([
                        Select::make('option_id')
                            ->reactive()
                            ->relationship('option','name')
                            ->columnSpan(1)
                            ->createOptionForm([
                                TextInput::make('name')
                                    ->required(),
                                ]),
                        Select::make('optionValues')
                            ->multiple()
                            ->preload()
                            ->relationship('optionValues','name', fn (Builder $query,callable $get) => $query->where('option_id',$get('option_id')))
                            ->createOptionForm([
                                Select::make('option_id')
                                    ->relationship('option','name'),
                                TextInput::make('name')
                                    ->required(),
                                ])
                            ->columnSpan(3)
                            ->reactive()
                        ])
```

I want the create form on the values to be like the following code:

```
Select::make('optionValues')
                            ->multiple()
                            ->preload()
                            ->relationship('optionValues','name', fn (Builder $query,callable $get) => $query->where('option_id',$get('option_id')))
                            ->createOptionForm([
                                TextInput::make('name')
                                    ->required(),
                                ])
                            ->columnSpan(3)
                            ->reactive()
```

where the option_id is just retrieved from the repeater.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pass data to forms just use this:

```php
->createOptionForm(fn(\Filament\Forms\Get $get) => [
    Select::make('option_id')
        ->relationship('option','name')
        ->default($get('option_id')),
    TextInput::make('name')
        ->required(),
])
```